# Webpack module federation is not working with eager shared libs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I was looking into Webpack 5 Module federation feature, and have some trouble understanding why my code does not work.
The idea is pretty similar to what standard module federation examples do:

`app1` - is the host app
`app2` - is a remote exposing the whole app to `app1`

(`app1` renders the header and horizontal line, below which the `app2` should be rendered)

Both `app1` and `app2` declares `react` and `react-dom` as their shared, singleton, eager dependencies in the `weback.config.js`:

```js
// app1 webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(SRC_DIR, './index.js');,
  ...
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "app1",
      remotes: {
        app2: `app2@//localhost:2002/remoteEntry.js`,
      },
      shared: { react: { singleton: true, eager: true }, "react-dom": { singleton: true, eager: true } },
    }),
    ...
  ],
};
```

```js
// app2 webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(SRC_DIR, './index.js');,
  ...
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "app2",
      library: { type: "var", name: "app2" },
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./App": "./src/App",
      },
      shared: { react: { singleton: true, eager: true }, "react-dom": { singleton: true, eager: true } },
    }),
    ...
  ],
};
```

In the App1 index.js I have next code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The App1 `App.js` component is next:

```js
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const RemoteApp2 = React.lazy(() => import("app2/App"));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>App 1</h1>
      <p>Below will be some content</p>
      <hr/>
      <Suspense fallback={'Loading App 2'}>
        <RemoteApp2 />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when I start the application I get the next error:

```
Uncaught Error: Shared module is not available for eager consumption: webpack/sharing/consume/default/react/react?1bb3
    at Object.__webpack_modules__.<computed> (consumes:133)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61)
    at Module../src/index.js (main.bundle.a8d89941f5dd9a37d429.js:239)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:21)
    at startup:4
    at startup:6
```

If I extract everything from `index.js` to `bootstrap.js` and in `index.js` will do

```js
import('./bootstrap');
```

Everything works just fine.

This confuses me as [official docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#troubleshooting) and [blog posts](https://medium.com/dev-genius/module-federation-advanced-api-inwebpack-5-0-0-beta-17-71cd4d42e534) from the creator states that you can do either `bootstrap.js` way OR declare dependency as an eager one.

Would appreciate any help/insights on why it does not work without `bootstrap.js` pattern.

Here is a link to full GitHub sandbox I was building: https://github.com/vovkvlad/webpack-module-fedaration-sandbox/tree/master/simple

Comment: I am a bit lost at the general concept, in particular: if I have a shell, and different UI's, let's say A and B (microfrontends), it is possible that the shell packs the React, react-dom, materialui dependencies and the A, B packages don't?
In my experiments, I see that the bundle size of shell, A and B are the same, so I suspect react, react-dom, etc are being bundled in ALL the apps, beating the goal of reducing bundle size by sharing remote dependencies. thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: @cesarpachon It is possible. To do it you have to configure Federation plugin to correctly resolve deps. I haven't worked with it for a while, but from what I remember: host app, app A and app B should all have react stated as a shared deps, and required version should meet. In that case it will be loaded only once.
Also do not forget to set eager to true for react as there should be only one such lib in the runtime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to make it work you need to change the way you are loading remote entry.

1. Update your `ModuleFederationPlugin` config in `webpack.config.js` for app1 to this:

```
...

new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: "app1",
    remoteType: 'var',
    remotes: {
      app2: 'app2',
    },
    shared: {
      ...packageJsonDeps,
      react: { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps.react },
      "react-dom": { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: packageJsonDeps["react-dom"] }
    },
}),

...
```

2. Add `script` tag to the `head` of your `index.html` in app1 :

```
<script src="http://localhost:2002/remoteEntry.js"></script>
```

Good look with further hacking!

UPDATE:

Just for the sake of it: I've create a PR to your sandbox repo with fixes described above:
https://github.com/vovkvlad/webpack-module-fedaration-sandbox/pull/2

Comment: So just to make things clear clear: your proposed changes do work, but as far as I understand from playing around with it, is that the bottom line is that the `remoteEntry.js` should be loaded BEFORE the bundle that actually runs the app.

And that's basically, what `bootstrap.js` does - it makes the main app to load after `main_bundle` and `remoteEntry.js`

When using your proposed change, it does the same - it downloads `remoteEntry.js` before the `main_bundle` as `main_bundle` is being added by webpack after hardcoded  script tag with `remoteEntry.js`

Comment: Here is a link with screenshots of all three situations:

https://imgur.com/a/63WTCMg

Comment: I'm having the same problem. And the suggested solution does not scale, if we are talking about development or a POC is ok, but when you have production-ready applications with 3+ environments this solution will not work.
If anyone has a solution that works with dynamic imports, I'm really interested how you solved this issue.

Comment: Is there any news regarding a solution without bootstrap file or add scripts to all remote entry?

Comment: can anyone help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75958591/nx-mfe-angular-module-federation-not-able-to-access-remote-micro-front-end

Answer (score 19):

Just to make it clear for those who might miss the comment to the initial answer:

It seems like the main reason of why it failed initially was that `remoteEntry.js` file was loaded after the code that actually runs the host app.

Both `bootstrap.js` approach and adding direct script `<script src="http://localhost:2002/remoteEntry.js"></script>` to the `<head></head>` tag has exactly the same outcome - they make `remoteEntry.js` be loaded and parsed **BEFORE** the main app's code.

In case of bootstrap the order is next:

1. `main_bundle` is loaded
2. as the main code is extracted into `bootstrap.js` file - `remoteEntry.js` is loaded
3. `bootstrap.js` is loaded which actually runs the main app

[image]

with proposed variant by Oleg Vodolazsky events order is next:

1. `remoteEntry.js` is loaded first as it is directly added to `html` file and webpack's `main_bundle` is being appended to `<head></head>` after remoteEntry link
2. `main_bundle` is loaded and runs the application

[image]

and in case of just trying to run app without bootstrap and without hardcoded script in the `<head></head>` `main_bundle` is loaded before `remoteEntry.js` and as `main_bundle` tries to actually run the app, it fails with an error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the dependency as eager inside the advanced API of Module Federation, which doesn’t put the modules in an async chunk, but provides them synchronously. This allows us to use these shared modules in the initial chunk. But be careful as all provided and fallback modules will always be downloaded. It’s recommended to provide it only at one point of your application, e.g. the shell.

Webpack's website strongly recommend using an asynchronous boundary. It will split out the initialization code of a larger chunk to avoid any additional round trips and improve performance in general.

For example, your entry looked like this:

```
index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Let's create bootstrap.js file and move contents of the entry into it, and import that bootstrap into the entry:

index.js

```
+ import('./bootstrap');
- import React from 'react';
- import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
- import App from './App';
- ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

bootstrap.js

```
+ import React from 'react';
+ import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
+ import App from './App';
+ ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This method works but can have limitations or drawbacks.

Setting eager: true for dependency via the ModuleFederationPlugin

webpack.config.js

```
// ...
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  shared: {
    ...deps,
    react: {
      eager: true,
    },
  },
});
```

[Source](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#uncaught-error-shared-module-is-not-available-for-eager-consumption)

Comment: Besides `import(".bootstrap")` are the remaining imports and ReactDom.Render() necessary in the `index.js` file?

Comment: @ChunkyChunk No it isn't necessary. Because we have it in bootstrap file.

Comment: I didn't notice the "+" and "-".  Now I understand what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced with problems when using NextJS app as a container app. You know, we had to give eager loaded again and again.

I followed a different way from current techniques on the web. I used dynamic load technique for my remote library and it seems shared modules are not being fetched again and again now. They are being loaded only once. Also, I implemented full system as framework agnostic so you can use any framework as a remote app (angular, vue, react, svelte...). Also, I moved SSR logic to remote app part so now it can fully support SSR for any framework, too. It seems worked and I wanted to share my solution in here to help community. I wrote a medium blog post with example Github repo link. I told my approach with details.

You can find detailed post in here: https://medium.com/@metinarslanturkk/how-i-implemented-dynamic-loaded-framework-agnostic-microfrontend-app-with-nextjs-and-react-which-620ff3df4298

And this is the example repo link: https://github.com/MetinArslanturk/microfrontend-nextjs-ssr

Thanks, Metin

Comment: Very interesting stuff! You really put a lot of work into this. Thanks for the guide and the git example. I actually looked at your code for quite a while, mostly next-host. Using it, I was finally able to load my react remote without getting the "Invalid hook" message