# How solve Shared module is not available for eager consumption typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I have created an application (app1) with the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "app1",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            exposes: {
                "./app1": "./src/components/Sidebar",
            },
            shared: [
                {
                    ...deps,
                    react: {
                        eager: true,
                        requiredVersion: deps.react,
                    },
                    "react-dom": {
                        eager: true,
                        requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
                    },
                    "react-redux": {
                        eager: true,
                        requiredVersion: deps["react-redux"],
                    },
                  ....
                  })
```

and the host applications with the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: "host",
            remotes: {
                app1: "app1@http://localhost:3002/remoteEntry.js",
            },
            shared: [
                {
                    ...deps,
                    react: {
                        eager: true,
                        requiredVersion: deps.react,
                    }
                },
            ]
        }),
```

When I start the host application it shows:

```
  Shared module is not available for eager 
  consumption:webpack/sharing/consume/default/react/react
```

I tried the `bootstrap.js` approach. In my case I created the `bootstrap.tsx` file, copied the content of the `index.tsx` into it, and then imported `bootstrap.tsx` in an `index.tsx`. Also added script tag with `remoteEntry.js` of app1. Still, it does not work.

If I comment the code in host application where I have called app1 component it works. But I use it then this error is coming.

How to resolve this?

In the following sequence, the files are getting called. Please check the image
[image]

Error goes like this
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack module federation is not working with eager shared libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123283/webpack-module-federation-is-not-working-with-eager-shared-libs)

Comment: I tried this too. But I see same error message

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#uncaught-error-shared-module-is-not-available-for-eager-consumption

Comment: If I comment the code in host application where I have called app1 component it works. But I use it then this error is coming.

Comment: Can you share a demo repo to debug? Hard to know without the code.

Comment: @dharmeshmehta found any solution ?

Comment: Did anyone find solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, my solution is:

1. The extension of bootstrap and index file should be `.js`
2. In `index.js` file, use `import('./bootstrap.js')` instead of `import './bootstrap.js'`

This works for me.

Comment: Had the same issue and resolved it with the same approach. IMO pretty disappointing issue.